# Dynamically give different names to fields so I can email them separately

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, email

Here's my setup so far: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BkpjQ/)

Whenever I click on the "Submit" button I need it to send an email to that specific person/email address.

But they all have the same names because I just cloned them. How do I dynamically give fields unique names and/or classes so I can email them separately?

`$('.sub_container').first().clone(true).appendTo('.container').find('input').val('');`

Also, since I will be dynamically adding new persons/email addresses, this must all happen on the same page. So I was thinking of using json or ajax perhaps?

Thanks in advance!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BkpjQ/)

Comment: I would rename your input fields in such a way that the request data is converted to an array for iteration, eg `name="people[0][Name]"` for the first person block, and `name="people[1][Name]"` for the second. You will still have to find a way to increment the index, or alternatively see if you can get away with simply using `name="people[][Name]"` for a self assigned index.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some thign like this

Add Hidden field for counter

```
<input type='hidden' id='counter' value ='0' />
```

changes to click event

```
$('.add_new').click(function (e) {
    var count = parseInt($("#counter").val(),10);
    $("#counter").val(count+1);
    var cloneEle = $(this).prev(".sub_container").clone(true); 
    cloneEle.attr("class","sub_container"+count)
 cloneEle.find("input[type='text']").val('');
    cloneEle.find('input[type="submit"]').val("Submit");
    cloneEle.find('input[type="submit"]').attr("id","btnSubmit"+count)
    cloneEle.appendTo('.container');
    $('.preview_message').last().html('');
    $('.preview_name').last().html('');
});
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/habo/BkpjQ/3/)